# Gitlab ci error : bash: composer: command not found

Tags: laravel, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I try to use pipeline with gitlab-ci

This is my gitlab-ci.ymn file

```
image: docker-laravel-envoy

services:
  - mysql:5.7

stages:
  - test

unit_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - composer install --prefer-dist --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts
    - php artisan key:generate
    - php artisan migrate
    - vendor/bin/phpunit
```

And this is the result of the pipeline

[image]

How can i choose the rigth image that will install composer
i tried several docker images but still getting the same result
i tried (is there a list of docker images where i can choose the one that corepond to my project)

- lorisleiva/laravel-docker:latest
- lorisleiva/laravel-docker:7.4

Do someone know where the problem is ?

### Gitlab runners

#### Shell gitlab runner

[image]

#### When i use docker gitlab runner

When i want to use a docker runner i get this issue
[image]

Im using a custom instalation of gitlab on my own server
Should i install docker on this server to resolve this issue ?

Comment: The shell runner uses the shell of the machine the runner's installed on. If you want to use a Docker image, use the Docker executor.

Comment: @Dan i edited my post with docker gitlab runner, I a still having an issue

Comment: Seems like you haven't followed the installation guide correctly. Docker must be installed on the runners' host. Personally I have all my runners installed via Docker, some on the machine Gitlab's running on and some on differently sized cloud servers.

Comment: It's not myself who has installed gitlab, Do you know how can i do it corectly ?